# Python Pandas compare two sheet and highlight similarities

Tags: python, pandas

My problem is pretty simple but I want your advice on the matter! I have an excel document that contains 2 sheets... The first sheet look like this :

```
Names
Ian Blake
Marc Twain
Bob Idol
Christian Charles
Able Duke
Grass Hopper
Two Cents
Eddie Murphy
Dennis Idol
Richard Blues
```

** The second sheet look like this :

```
Names
Hopper, Grass
Idol, Bob
Twain , Marc
Horse, Noname
Blues, Richard
Murphy, Eddie
Black, Stallion
Cents, Two
Idol, Dennis
Blake, Ian
Charles, Christian
Duke, Able
Louis, Joe
```

What I need is to highlights name that are present in sheet1 and sheet2 (Ex: Ian Black is sheet1 and 2) but as you can see the name are displayed in a different way in sheet2... The names can be highlight only in sheet2... So if there a better language then Python to do that or if there a way with Python please tell me!

Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: When you say 'highlight' do you want to highlight them inside the Excel file or would printing out the values of interest?

Comment: Highlights in the same file if possible or extract the names that are present in the two sheets and put them in another one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, assuming your data is in excell file, you should be able to read that. Install [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/):
`pip install openpyxl`
Now Here is my solution to `print` similar values in console.
I assume that in `Sheet2`, all names are in this format:
`last_name, first_name`
and in `Sheet1`, all names are in this format:
`first_name last_name`
So here is a pythonic solution to do what you want:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_excel('<file_name>.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1', engine='openpyxl')
df2 = pd.read_excel('<file_name>.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet2', engine='openpyxl')

df2['Names'] = df2['Names'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x.split(', ')[::-1]))
print(df1.merge(df2, left_on='Names', right_on='Names'))
```

Output:

```
           Names
0          Ian Blake
1           Bob Idol
2  Christian Charles
3          Able Duke
4       Grass Hopper
5          Two Cents
6       Eddie Murphy
7        Dennis Idol
8      Richard Blues
```

And finally if you want to write output to an excell file:

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, left_on='Names', right_on='Names')
df3.to_excel('out.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet3', engine='openpyxl')
```

Comment: The things is that the list of names will always be different and there is multiple excel file to extract the similar names in the two sheets and is there a way to write the output in a new sheet

Comment: i don't get the first part. Can you explain exactly what is not included in my answer? You want to write the output in another excell file?

Comment: The code is doing what I want basically but is just how you declare the dataframe by writing down all the name in the list but is there a way to just put the column name (names) without writing all the names but still check all name in the column (names) in both sheet for similarities and output it in another sheet

Comment: You want to read names directly from two excell files and not do like `pd.DataFrame`? Like for example: `pd.read_excel('file.xlsx, sheet_name='Sheet1') `

Comment: Yes exactly ! Would that work the same ? just need to change : df1 = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx, sheet_name='Sheet1') and df2 = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx, sheet_name='Sheet2')

Comment: Yep, I will change my answer to do that.